# Comparing elements within Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Suppose I have a list of item and I transform it into list of another type using Stream. Suppose also that the original `itemList` is retrieved from the database and is ordered by last updated time stamp and I would want to preserve the ordering. (so that cannot sort the Stream). I want to find out the maximum price among those elements and if it is, then set the isMax indicator in the ItemResponse. How to do it if I want to do this using the same Stream ?

One way I think of is to create another Stream to compare it, however, it appears to be duplicate effort (looping over the same elements twice).

Or is it better to not Stream in this case and transform the original Stream back to for loop ?

```
List<Item> itemList = Arrays.asList(
                    new Item(BigDecimal.valueOf(10), 1),
                    new Item(BigDecimal.valueOf(20), 2));

List<ItemResponse> itemResponseList = itemList.stream()
                        .map(item -> {
                            ItemResponse itemResponse = new ItemResponse();
                            itemResponse.setId(item.getId());
                            itemResponse.setPrice(item.getAmount());
//adding logic to find the max and set the max indicator, but how ?
        
                            return itemResponse;
                        })
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    

//attempt 1 - it works, but it loops the same elements again
Optional<ItemResponse> max = itemResponseList.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingDouble(itemResponse -> itemResponse.getPrice().doubleValue())));
                    max.ifPresent(e -> e.setMax(true));


public class Item {

    private BigDecimal amount;
    private int id;

    Item(BigDecimal amount, int id) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class ItemResponse {

    private BigDecimal price;
    private Boolean isMax;
    private int id;

    ItemResponse() {};

    public Boolean getMax() {
        return isMax;
    }

    public void setMax(Boolean max) {
        isMax = max;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id: " + id + ", price: " + price + ", isMax: " + isMax;
    }
}
```

Comment: The function passed to `map` is evaluated for every element of the stream. You surely do not want to repeat the search for the maximum for every element. Besides that, your search for the maximum is unnecessarily complicated. Just use `itemResponseList.stream() .max(Comparator.comparing(ItemResponse::getPrice))` and use `boolean` instead of `Boolean`, so the default value will be `false` rather than `null`.

Comment: Could multiple itemsResponse instances have `getMax() == true` or just one?

Comment: There can be multiple itemsResponse instances have getMax() == true

Comment: Then, there is no way around doing one pass over the `itemList` to get the maximum price first, followed by the conversion loop which can compare the current item’s price with the maximum. This would also be the only solution supporting immutable objects, by the way. Of course, either pass could be implemented as loop or stream operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that in general case multiple items may have maximum and/or minimum price, it appears that the stream approach does not help to avoid duplicate iteration.  Instead, a loop should be used to convert the items into item responses and build two intermediate lists of items with maximum / minimum prices, and after that iterate the smaller lists and set appropriate indicators.

```java
List<ItemResponse> itemResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
List<ItemResponse> maxPriced = new ArrayList<>();
List<ItemResponse> minPriced = new ArrayList<>();

BigDecimal minPrice = null;
BigDecimal maxPrice = null;

for (Item item : itemList) {
    ItemResponse ir = new ItemResponse();
    ir.setId(item.getId());
    ir.setPrice(item.getAmount());
    if (null == minPrice || minPrice.compareTo(ir.getPrice()) >= 0) {
        if (null == minPrice || minPrice.compareTo(ir.getPrice()) > 0) {
            minPrice = ir.getPrice();
            minPriced.clear();
        }
        minPriced.add(ir);
    }
    if (null == maxPrice || maxPrice.compareTo(ir.getPrice()) <= 0) {
        if (null == maxPrice || maxPrice.compareTo(ir.getPrice()) < 0) {
            maxPrice = ir.getPrice();
            maxPriced.clear();
        }
        maxPriced.add(ir);
    }
    itemResponseList.add(ir);
}
minPriced.forEach(i -> i.setMin(true));
maxPriced.forEach(i -> i.setMax(true));
```

Or, it may be better just to prepare and run a query on the database to get max/min prices and then use these values to set indicators in *one stream*.

```java
BigDecimal[] minMax = getMinMaxPrices(); // {min. max}

List<ItemResponse> itemResponseList = itemList
    .stream()
    .map(item -> {
        ItemResponse itemResponse = new ItemResponse();
        itemResponse.setId(item.getId());
        itemResponse.setPrice(item.getAmount());
        itemResponse.setMin(item.getAmount().equals(minMax[0]));
        itemResponse.setMax(item.getAmount().equals(minMax[1]));
        return itemResponse;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a decreasing order sorted list and update just the head of the list.

```java
List<Item> itemList = Arrays.asList(
                    new Item(BigDecimal.valueOf(10), 1),
                    new Item(BigDecimal.valueOf(20), 2));

List<ItemResponse> itemResponseList = itemList.stream()
                        .map(item -> {
                            ItemResponse itemResponse = new ItemResponse();
                            itemResponse.setId(item.getId());
                            itemResponse.setPrice(item.getAmount());
                            return itemResponse;
                        })
                        // reverse sorting
                        .sorted(Comaparator.comparing(ItemResponse::getPrice).reversed())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// only first will be updated, if the list is non-empty
itemResponseList.stream().findFirst().ifPresent(e -> e.setMax(true));
```

Comment: While the use of `getPrice().doubleValue()` for comparison was already in the OP’s code, I’d not repeat this questionable pattern. `BigDecimal` is already comparable and a conversion to `double` is lossy and expensive. Just use `Comparator.comparing(ItemResponse::getPrice).reversed()`

Comment: Thank you. Regarding using the same pattern OP was concerned about looping through the list twice, while in this way, we loop through just once and just check the head/first of the list again. So, looks like a good deal computation wise.

Comment: Suppose the itemList is retrieved from the database ordered by last updated timestamp and would want to preserve the ordering without using sorting in the Stream. It appears that even if not using Stream but a for loop, it will still need a minimum of two iterations to get this done.

Comment: @sea you can do it in one loop when the loop does both, create the `ItemResponse` and add it to the result list and remember the `ItemResponse` having the maximum price. However, don’t be afraid to iterate a list twice. It’s not that expensive. In fact, there are cases where the JVM’s optimizer creates better code for single-concern loops. Only when iterating over an expensive resource like lines of a file or items from a network stream or database rows, avoiding multiple iterations is a concern.

Comment: @AlexRudenko the OP added that statement to the question after the answer has been posted.